# Reading JSON WebResponse

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

I'm using this function to get the response of my requested URL.
Not any error occurring with this function but the value it returns isn't what I want.

Here is the response from Firefox:

[image]

The function returns the HTML part but doesn't return the `nextCursorEndpoint` part. I want to get the `nextCursorEndpoint` part.

My code:

```
Private Function GET_Request(ByVal URL As String, ByVal CC As CookieContainer) As String
    Try
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
        With req
            .Method = "GET"
            .CookieContainer = CC
            .UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
        End With

        Using response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
            Using resStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using streamReader As New StreamReader(resStream, Encoding.UTF8)
                    Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        InvokeIfRequired(ListBox2, DirectCast(Sub() ListBox2.Items.Add("[" & TimeString & "]:" & ex.Message), MethodInvoker))
        Return GET_Request(URL, CC)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: According to that screen shot, the value you're looking for was in fact returned by the server.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The function I'm using doesn't return all the response , it just returns the html part without the nextCursorEndpoint which exactly i want.
I added the function in my questions because i forgot it.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `response` and the result of `GET_Request()` as seen from the debugger?  This code would return the entire response, so either something outside of this code isn't doing what you expect or the server isn't returning what you expect.  (Also, you might want to re-think your `Catch` block.  That's an infinite recursion waiting to happen.)

Comment: The response is too long to post it here.
but inside the picture you can see two parts. The result I got from GET_Request() is the same as the second part which starts with <div class=" Timeline-item" role="row">

Comment: It really sounds like you're going to have to do some debugging then.  There's nothing in this code that is filtering (or even attempting to parse) JSON properties in that response.

Comment: Can you explain more what should I do to know what's the problem ? :)

Comment: Given the code presented, all I can suggest is looking at the contents of the `response` variable and specifically what the response stream contains.  If this method is indeed returning the wrong string, then that means the server is returning the wrong string.  This method isn't filtering anything.

Comment: the response doesn't even contain the word "cursor" which should be in it.
Why could the server return wrong string ?
I tried it manually and saw the response from Firefox browser and isn't same as the method. As i said before the function gets me only a part of it. Also as you said there's no filtering in the function. That's why I got mad of this problem

Comment: Examine the headers and other request details being sent to the server.  Maybe it's returning different responses based on that.  It could be that Firefox is sending different headers than the code is.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem.I've missed the "Accept" header. How can I accept your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [based on comments in the question above...]

The code in the question isn't doing any kind of filtering.  So I *strongly* suspect that the server isn't returning what you expect it to.  A very likely culprit for this could simply be the headers being sent in the request.

You're going to want to examine these closely during debugging.  Firefox may simply be sending different headers than your code is sending, and the server-side logic for that resource may respond differently.

**For example:** If the `Accept` header is different and/or missing, than that could be signaling the server to provide different types of responses.